# When and when not to use TypeVars?

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing

When using the `typing` module to write type hints, I'm not sure when and when not I am supposed to use `TypeVar` instances.

For example, what's the practical "difference" between

```
str_or_int = typing.TypeVar('str_or_int', str, int)
```

and

```
str_or_int = typing.Union[str, int]
```

used in a hint like this?

```
def foo(bar: str_or_int):
    pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
T = TypeVar('T', str, int)

def foo(bar: T) -> T:
    pass
```

This is how typevars are used. This means `bar` could be either a `str` or `int` and `foo` will return a value of the same type as `bar` was. You won't get that with a `Union`:

```
str_or_int = Union[str, int]

def foo(bar: str_or_int) -> str_or_int:
    pass
```

This just means that `bar` can be a `str` or `int` and that `foo` will return a `str` or `int`, there's no connection between the type of `bar` and the return value.

Comment: Thanks! In cases where this difference does not matter (such as the `foo` in my OP), what's the preferred class to use?

Comment: With `TypeVar` you're always establishing a connection. It's a *variable name* in your type system. Don't use it unless that's what you want, or you may see unexpected side effects.